# How to access environment variables in dbt Python model

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

- https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/environment-variables
- https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var

These documents only explain about how to access environment variables in dbt SQL model.
How can I do it in dbt dython model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you cannot expand jinja templates in python dbt models, i used to have a workaround.

Suppose you have variable defined in project config.

**dbt_project.yml:**

```
...
vars:
  my_var: my_value
```

then, you can use jinja in model config itself to pass this value.

**my_model_scheme.yml**

```
models:
  - name: model_my
    config:
      materialized: incremental
      tags: [ 'python' ]
      my_var: '{{ var("my_var") }}'
```

And finally get it in model.

**model_my.py**

```
def model(dbt, session):
    print(dbt.config.get("my_var"))
```

Comment: Thanks, official document also suggests to use config https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/python-models#accessing-project-context